# How to get "mounted on" in python for external devices

Tags: python, usb, mount

I'm trying to detect all the USB pen drives on my raspberry pi in python. And I want all their mount locations. I've checked the APi, but I can't find how I can select the mount point for the devices.

```
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
  ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
  ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')
  output=[]
  for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
    device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
    device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)

    if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsRemovable"):
      temp = []
      **## HOW DO I GET THE MOUNTED ON I SEE IN df -h ?**
      output.append(temp)
  return output
```

This is what I need:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          2.6G  2.2G  313M  88% /
/dev/root       2.6G  2.2G  313M  88% /
devtmpfs        112M     0  112M   0% /dev
tmpfs            24M  228K   23M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1        15G  581M   15G   4% **/media/usb0**  <--- I need these
tmpfs            47M     0   47M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M  9.5M   47M  17% /boot
/dev/sda        3.8G  1.1M  3.8G   1% **/media/usb1**  <--- I need these
```

For every external USB device I want an array with following information: 
[manufacturer,total size Human readable (GB),mount point first partition, total size in KB,available size in KB]

EDIT:

I changed my code to this:

```
def USBDEVICES():
  bus = dbus.SystemBus()
  ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
  ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')
  output=[]
  for dev in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
    device_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", dev)
    device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)

    if device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsRemovable"):
      temp = []
      temp.append(str(device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DriveVendor")))
      temp.append(str(math.ceil(device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "PartitionSize")/1048576.0)/1000)+' GB')
      temp.append(device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "DeviceIsMounted"))
      temp.append(device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device','DeviceMountPaths'))
      output.append(temp)
  print output
```

I was hoping to get this output:

[['TDKMedia', '15.255 GB',True,'/media/usb0'],['Sony', '3.812 GB',True,'/media/usb1']

But instead I got this:

[['TDKMedia', '15.255 GB', dbus.Boolean(False, variant_level=1), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1)], ['USB2.0', '3.812 GB', dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1), dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'/media/usb1')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1)]]

No mount path for the TDKMedia USB Drive and something strange for the other USB drive.
But when I look at df, it says the TDK is mounted... :/

Since the main question has been solved, I've opened a new topic for the not mounted problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928984/python-dbus-acting-weird

Comment: Is parsing the output of `mount` or `df` an option?

Comment: I think so, but I only need external usb devices and I have absolutely no idea how to do that (new to linux and python) and I also want for every external usb device an array with following inofrmation: [manufacturer,total size Human readable (GB),mount point first partition, total size in KB,available size in KB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device` documentation](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/1.0.5/Device.html), there are the following properties for a `Device`:

> The `DeviceIsMounted` property
>
> > `TRUE` if the device is mounted.
>
> The `DeviceMountPaths` property
>
> > A list of paths in the root namespace where the root of the device is
> >     mounted. This property is only valid if `DeviceIsMounted` is `TRUE`.

Alas I am unable to verify, but something as follows ought to work then:

```
if (device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', 'DeviceIsRemovable') and
        device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', 'DeviceIsMounted')):
    output.extend(device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device',
                                   'DeviceMountPaths'))
```

Comment: I'm running a stability test on my pi right now. I think I already tried what you suggest and I think it gave me the /dev/sda  and /dev/sdb, but I'm not 100% sure (I found it very strange because I alsoe read the api documentation) But as soon as I've tested it, I'll let you know. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is what I get from it: signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1) for the other usb stick I get this: dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'/media/usb1')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1)

Comment: I've edited my question. Very strange results I'm getting. :(